# Bash script separate logs from one pod to another

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

How can I separate the logs from one pod to another?
Below is what I worked on:

```
CrashLoopBackOff=`for i in $(kubectl get po -n namespace | grep CrashLoopBackOff | awk '{print $1}'); do echo $i; done`
for y in $CrashLoopBackOff; do 
    k8s_logs=`kubectl logs $y -n namespace | tail -10` arr2+="$k8s_logs\n"
done
```

But the output is all together for 2 crashed pods or more pods and I cannot differentiate the logs from each pod. Any idea how can I put an echo or something between each pod log?

```
2021-03-12 07:30:11.622 [ERROR] [gstp_server_app.cc:4007] Failed to start subscription from SEL
2021-03-12 07:30:11.622 [ERROR] [gstp_server_app.cc:4010] Exception:    0 In order to do catch up, static entity: must have history enabled.

2021-03-12 07:30:11.622 [FATAL] [gstp_server_app.cc:1441] JMS Catchup initialization error.
2021-03-12 07:30:11.622 [FATAL] [gstp_server_app.cc:695] Failed to connect to JMS for data
2021-03-12 07:30:13.188 [INFO ] [jms_server.cc:495] End JMSServer.run
Ending JMSServer::Run
GSTP JMS Server Application Shutting down.
255
2021-03-12 07:31:51.828 [ERROR] [rcltocvll.cc:325] Zero Curve does not exist for DEPOT asof 02/06/12.
2021-03-12 07:31:51.831 [ERROR] [gbdopspec.cc:297] Error Creating Curve List Out Of Risk Class 
2021-03-12 07:31:51.831 [ERROR] [sectheo.cc:705] Error retrieving security curves.
2021-03-12 07:31:51.833 [ERROR] [sectheo.cc:999] Error computing theoretical price for Security 
2021-03-12 07:31:51.833 [ERROR] [rcltocvll.cc:325] Zero Curve does not exist for DEPOT asof 02/06/12.
2021-03-12 07:31:51.833 [ERROR] [gbdopspec.cc:297] Error Creating Curve List Out Of Risk Class List
2021-03-12 07:31:51.833 [ERROR] [sectheo.cc:705] Error retrieving security curves.
2021-03-12 07:31:51.833 [ERROR] [sectheo.cc:999] Error computing theoretical price for Security 
bash: line 1:     6 Killed                  gstp_server_jms -N -LOGGER INFO -CFG
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't forget to give part of `kubectl get po -n namespace`'s output for people to know what kind of data you are working on.

Also, the backquote (`` ` ``) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g. `` foo=`command` `` . The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 to learn how to read lines of input

The rest of your code is not even working, so here is working code based on my assumptions on what you tried to achieve:

```sh
arr2=()
while read -r crashing_pod _; do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr2+=("$crashing_pod: $line")
    # arr2+=("$line")
  done < <(kubectl logs "$crashing_pod" -n namespace | tail -10)
  # arr2+=('' "end of $crashing_pod 's logs" '')
done < <(kubectl get po -n namespace | grep CrashLoopBackOff)

printf %s\\n "${arr2[@]}"
```

You'll see I have prepended each line with the pod name, but you can use the two commented  outlines instead if you'd rather have a separator like requested.